# How can I make a tabControl1.DrawItem use a specific color for the background in C#?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, controls

I followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for creating a side aligned tab control. But if I change the background color of the form itself, I'm left with white areas in the tabControl (see picture). How can I either make the tabControl either transparent or match the color of the form?

[image]

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush _textBrush;

        // Get the item from the collection.
        TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

        // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
        Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {

            // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
            _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            e.DrawBackground();
        }

        // Use our own font.
        Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Draw string. Center the text.
        StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
        _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows forms you have the ability to dock specific anchor points. If you dock the points with the parent window, you should eliminate those gaps.

Comment: Why did this get marked down? The default padding of the controls is caused by a lack of anchoring...